# Limit number of cores in nondaemon pool Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a script where I running some processes with pool.apply_async and running them as nondaemon to avoid issues of "zombie" processes overwhelming memory wise. It's been working well so far, except that now I have scaled to a larger dataset in memory so by using all my cores I am blowing up memory wise. I want to limit the number of cores used in those cases, but can't get it to work

Normally I would integrate something like the following

```py
    pool = Pool(self.nb_cores)
```

to limit the number of cores. However I can't seem to find out where to integrate it into a nondeamon process.

```py
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.pool

class NoDaemonProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    """
    Extends the multiprocessing Process class to disable
    the daemonic property. Polling the daemonic property
    will always return False and cannot be set.
    """

    @property
    def daemon(self):
        """
        Always return False
        """
        return False

    @daemon.setter
    def daemon(self, value):
        """
        Pass over the property setter

        :param bool value: Ignored setting
        """
        pass

class NoDaemonContext(type(multiprocessing.get_context())):
    """
    With the new multiprocessing module, everything is based
    on contexts after the overhaul. This extends the base
    context so that we set all Processes to NoDaemonProcesses
    """

    Process = NoDaemonProcess

class NoDaemonPool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    """
    This extends the normal multiprocessing Pool class so that
    all spawned child processes are non-daemonic, allowing them
    to spawn their own children processes.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['context'] = NoDaemonContext()
        super(NoDaemonPool, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know I need to integrate a number of cores limit somewhere ... just can't seem to find the precise function I need in my context.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `NoDaemonPool` class is derived from [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) therefore will be able to accept `processes` (the number of worker processes to use) as keyword argument:

```
pool = NoDaemonPool(processes=nb_cores)
```